# Verifying username and password with php and MYSQL

Tags: php, pdo

I am using a basic PHP create account and sign in template I found online. However, after creating an account, every time I try to log in i get incorrect username/password.
I am new to PHP and have been banging my head against the wall trying to identify where the error is. So I wonder if someone here would be able to help?

```
 public function __construct( $data = array() ) {
         if( isset( $data['username'] ) ) $this->username = stripslashes( strip_tags( $data['username'] ) );
         if( isset( $data['password'] ) ) $this->password = stripslashes( strip_tags( $data['password'] ) );
     }

     public function storeFormValues( $params ) {
        //store the parameters
        $this->__construct( $params ); 
     }

     public function userLogin() {
         $success = false;
         try{
            $con = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD ); 
            $con->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM user_accounts WHERE username = :username AND password = :password LIMIT 1";
            $stmt = $con->prepare( $sql );
            $stmt->bindValue( ":username", $this->username, PDO::PARAM_STR );
            $stmt->bindValue( ":password", hash("whirlpool", $this->password . $this->salt), PDO::PARAM_STR );
            $stmt->execute();

            $valid = $stmt->fetchColumn();

            if( $valid ) {
                $success = true;
            }

            $con = null;
            return $success;
         }catch (PDOException $e) {
             echo $e->getMessage();
             return $success;
         }
     }

     public function register() {
        $correct = false;
            try {
                $con = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
                $con->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
                $sql = "INSERT INTO user_accounts(username, password) VALUES(:username, :password)";

                $stmt = $con->prepare( $sql );
                $stmt->bindValue( ":username", $this->username, PDO::PARAM_STR );
                $stmt->bindValue( ":password", hash("whirlpool", $this->password . $this->salt), PDO::PARAM_STR );
                $stmt->execute();
                return "Registration Successful <br/> <a href='index.php'>Login Now</a>";
            }catch( PDOException $e ) {
                return $e->getMessage();
            }
     }

 }

?>
```

Comment: you can check  by  echoing the password that you are saving in db and the pass of the user  with which you are trying to login .

Comment: can you var_dump $data in the __constructor ?

Comment: From var_dump($data); i get the following output: array(0) { } array(3) { ["username"]=> string(12) "testusername" ["password"]=> string(12) "testpassword" ["login"]=> string(9) "Log me in" } Incorrect Username/Password

Comment: Where do you get `$this->salt` from? If it's random - it'll never work ;) If it's constant.. it's not that secure.

Comment: (apologises about my formatting, I am new to the site) @kocik I get salt from the following:[code] class Users { public $username = null; public $password = null; public $salt ="Zo4rU5Z1YyKJAASY0PT6EUg7BBYdlEhPaNLuxAwU8lqu1ElzHv0Ri7EM6irpx5w"[/code]

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, unfortunately. What I would do is var_dump `$this->username` and result of a `hash` fnction just before the executing the query in register and userLogin, check if the results are the same, and then I would check what I actually have in my database (phpMyAdmin or console) and if that matches my input :)